# Issue regarding multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to retrieve values from a multidimensional array. In this case below code is working

```
echo $orderList['Orders']['Order'][1]['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['SKU'];
```

But this is not working

```
for($i=0;$i<count($orderList);$i++)
{
$order_info['order_sku'] = $orderList['Orders']['Order'][$i]['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['SKU'];
}
```

Can anyone say what is the problem ??

***UPDATE***

Actually my array like below.I would like to retrieve `RowId` value; Thanks

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [OrderItems] => Array
                (
                    [OrderItem] => Array
                       (
                            [RowId] => 1
                        )
                )
         )
)
```

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<count($orderList['Orders']['Order']);$i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
for($i=0;$i<count($orderList['Orders']['Order']);$i++) { ... }
```

or even

```
foreach($orderList['Orders']['Order'] as $order) {
    $order_info['order_sku'] = $order['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['SKU'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($orderList);$i++) {
   $order_info['order_sku'] = $orderList[$i]['OrderItems']['OrderItem']['RowId'];
}
```